# SSRS page numbers incorrect in pdf format

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, pdf-generation, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I am generating a SSRS report from SQL2014.

The report renders correctly when looked at in the Report Builder preview, but when exported to pdf the report numbers are incorrect.

In my test report there are three  "reports" each 1 page long. So each page should be page 1 of 1, but the middle page ends up being page 2 of 1.

If I print a report with just 1 multi page "Report" the page numbers work fine.

I'm using what I think is a standard expression for page numbers:

```
=Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages
```

I see the same issue when I export to tiff.

Comment: If each page should be "1 of 1" why is it an expression?

Comment: Updated to better reflect what I mean

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ResetPageNumber` property on the last table for each report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this function from [msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrishays/2006/01/05/reset-page-number-on-group/)

```
 Shared offset as Integer
 Shared currentgroup as Object

 Public Function GetGroupPageNumber(group as Object, pagenumber as Integer) as Object
  If Not (group = currentgroup)
     offset = pagenumber – 1
     currentgroup = group
  End If

  Return pagenumber – offset
 End Function
```

Along with the tablix member to name the page based on the group by setting the `PageName` property under Group to the ID of my group, then using the following expression for my totals, and to reset the page nums:

```
=Code.GetGroupPageNumber(Globals!PageName, Globals!PageNumber) & " of " & Globals!TotalPages
```

Seems to get me out of the wood, I'm not sure if its the "right" way to do it though.